# Programmatically send SMS in windows phone 8 without user interaction

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to send SMS programmatically in Windows Phone 8 without user interaction? I've looked around but all solutions expects that user click send button. 
I don't limit to C#, I think about C++ but for now I don't have any good solutions of this problem.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible to do.
Your only way is the SmsComposeTask.

Comment: Even usung nativ C++ language is this impossible?